# How can i change :-webkit-full-screen{} CSS with JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

With JQuery i can change CSS. Example:

```
$("iframe").css("z-index","2147483648");
```

How can i change this `iframe:-webkit-full-screen{z-index:2147483647}`
[image]

Comment: http://www.rainbodesign.com/pub/css/css-javascript.html

Comment: Why don't you just edit this with css? Add a class using js and use CSS for styles. I am not sure if it is possible to target that with jquery